# Order of integration for $\int_{0}^{T-N}\left\{ \int_{b}^{b+N}f(b,t)dt\right\} db$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{T-N}\left\{ \int_{b}^{b+N}f(b,t)dt\right\} db$$

How can I change the order of integration. $T$ and $N$ are constant variables. I tried to make a graphic which gives a paralleogram shape but after I could not understand how to change the order in a correct way.

Comment: I think you should have a look at Fubini's theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bounds of integration are not an issue for the Fubini-Tonelli theorem since
$$
\int_{0}^{T-N}\left\{ \int_{b}^{b+N}f(b,t)dt\right\} db=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}f(b,t)\cdot \boldsymbol{1}_{[b,b+N]}(t) \cdot \boldsymbol{1}_{[0,T-N]}(b)\,d(t,b).
$$

Answer (score 2):

First substitute $t=s+b$

$$\int_{0}^{T-N}\left( \int_{b}^{b+N}f(b,t)~\mathsf dt\right)\mathsf db=\int_0^{T-N}\left(\int_0^N f(b,s+b)~\mathsf d s\right)\mathsf d b$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, to convert the second integral to $dt$, I put $s=0$ and $s=N$. Since $s=t-b$, I will have $\int_{t-N}^{t}\left(\int_{0}^{N}f\left(b,t\right)db\right)dt$. Is it correct, no?

Comment: No. You have to swap the order of the integrals (not just the variables, the bounds as well).  Reality check: you should not have the variable of integration occuring in the bounds of the same integral.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Fubini do it yourself]

Nothing new, just wanted to illustrate how you can figure that out yourself in the future.